# Bash Heredoc format adding a new line at the end of );

Tags: bash, heredoc

I'm trying to create a bash script to create automated sql statements to run them in DB without the effort of manually modify the .sql script and avoid human error, there is an issue when it generates the output files using heredoc format, is adding a new line at the end of the bash script where sql statement end in **);**
I know this can be easy thing like scape this characters but I tried to scape them with backslash and is not working, here is my example:

```
   cat <<EOF >> $updateTabletmp
INSERT INTO ${table}_${currentTimeStamp}
SELECT * FROM ${table} WHERE field_1= ${count} AND field_2 = (SELECT field_2
FROM bartable WHERE field_2 = ${store});
EOF
```

This is the current output:

```
INSERT INTO foo_123419294
SELECT * FROM PHYPIOEE WHERE field_1 = 2177 AND field_2= (SELECT field_2
FROM bartable WHERE field_2 = 8788
);
```

As you can see of some reason ); is moved as a new line, the expected output will be something like this:

```
INSERT INTO foo_123419294
SELECT * FROM PHYPIOEE WHERE field_1 = 2177 AND field_2= (SELECT field_2
FROM bartable WHERE field_2 = 8788);
```

Thanks

Comment: The value of `$store` ends with a trailing newline; how was it set? (Note this has nothing to do with the here-doc itself.)

Comment: This, by the way, is a terrible way to construct a SQL query unless you are extremely careful about how the various variables are set.

Comment: I'm getting this from a .txt file where I have count;store
So I read the file, I do the split by ; and then get the count in a variable and store in another, `count=$(echo $line | awk -F';' '{print $1}')` and `store=$(echo $line | awk -F';' '{print $2}')`, is this because the CR LF characters in the file?

Comment: by the way, how would you do these SQL statements using bash to create an .sql script?

Comment: @JavierSalas `$(command)` automatically removes the trailing newline from the output of the command. If the file has CRLF characters, this will result in `$store` ending with `CR`, but not `LF`. So it doesn't really explain the result you're seeing.

Comment: BTW, that's a complicated way to split a variable into two. `IFS=';' read -r count store <<<"$line"` is better.

Comment: Another thing: when you do `echo $line` instead of `echo "$line"`, the CR LF will be ignored.

Comment: But the result you're seeing does point to `$store` ending with newline for some reason. You need to post a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @JavierSalas I probably wouldn't. I'd use a language with a decent SQL library to generate and execute the query.

Comment: @Javier Please post the output of `declare -p store` right above running your command. (Could be it's LF+CR, so `$(..)` does not remove LF)

Comment: Hi all, I've resolved the issue, it was on reading the file, as it had CRLF characters, what I did was to remove them with Notepad++ and just keep LF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just tested your script and it does not add any unexpected new line/s

```
#!/bin/sh
 
out=out.txt
table=table
currentTimeStamp=12345678
count=123
store=asdf
 
cat <<EOF >> $out
INSERT INTO ${table}_${currentTimeStamp}
SELECT * FROM ${table} WHERE field_1= ${count} AND field_2 = (SELECT field_2
FROM bartable WHERE field_2 = ${store});
EOF
```

and the result is:

```
INSERT INTO table_12345678
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field_1= 123 AND field_2 = (SELECT field_2
FROM bartable WHERE field_2 = asdf);
```

So the reason can be only one: your `${store}` variable contains new line.
And that's the answer.

Comment: Hi @tansy, you're right, it was not regarding to `${store}` variable, but it was due file that was reading had CRLF characters and that caused that.

Comment: You're welcome. Next time isolate and simplify block of code you suspect and experiment with it and you will solve it yourself.